# Problems connecting to server (ssh, no route to host)

Tags: networking, ssh, routing, port-forwarding, port

I have a home server that's been working fine for the past few months. For the network configuration, I've assigned it a static IP, and various ports have been forwarded, e.g. 22, 80, 8080, 443, 5904, and a few others. Up until now, I've been able to connect via ssh no problem, but just recently, I have begun to get the "no route to host" error. Also, the web server that runs on it seems to be inaccessible.

The server is running in a remote location so it's difficult to diagnose. I've tried restarting it and the router, but the problem persists.

Any ideas as to what could have caused this error to start appearing?

Comment: Have you verified that your SSh daemon is still up and running? - There are many reasons why it could have gone offline, and it may require nothing more than restarting ...or is the SSh on your end, and the webserver on the other (it is unclear from your post)?

Answer (score 0):

No route to host indicates that the IP address is not known to the network. 
I would look at your router and see if the physical connection to the server is correct. 
Try connecting directly to the router the server is connected to and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I'm an idiot - turns out that the ISP gave us a new public IP address. Should have been the first thing I checked for!

Thanks for the suggestions.